# Port forwarding Actiontec GT784WN with CenturyLink static IP

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, static-ip

We have a static IP through CenturyLink and are connecting to the internet just fine with our Actiontec GT784WN. We have installed a device that needs port forwarding.

I've gone to the Advanced Setup and added all the ports to forward to the LAN IP address of the device.

When checking with an open port scanner, I get the following results:

443 - filtered
1433-1434 - filtered
7100-7130 - closed

I'm not sure if I need to disable NAT, enable DMZ, or something else. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you have a spot that hosts images, you might want to add a screenshot of the setup page on the router; I realize that as a new user, you can't post one directly yet.  I wouldn't bother with the open port scanner, but I wonder if you have the port forwarding to the right port on the device, not just the IP address.

Comment: Yes, [here are my settings](http://i.imgur.com/TJ3dPuv.jpg). The device is a POS server that our provider installed for us, so I'm assuming (maybe incorrectly) that all the configuration on that device is correct.

Answer (score 0):

With some ISP's (usually with home packages) you may have to request ports to be unblocked. It's worth giving them a call just to check. Failing that, try it with a spare router? Try a different port query tool?

The above isn't really an answer, I know, but a few things to try.

Comment: It is a business line and they said they are not blocking any ports. We had a different router before moving to this one and had the same issue. Have tried multiple tools as well. Thank you though!

Comment: I'd try disabling all firewalls next?

Comment: I attempted to forward those ports to my computer and completely disabled my firewall and still did not have any luck.